# Reading and modifying lines in a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm just getting started with Ruby, and my first program reads from a txt file and prints a modified version of each line to another one. The idea is to get this:

```
- Book Title *Book Author*
```

To this:

```
  Book Title     Book Author
```

My code looks like this:

```
listold = File.open('listas.txt', 'r+')
listnew = File.new('lista.txt', 'w+')
listold.each_line {|line|
  nome, autor = line.split(' *')
  nome['- '] = '  '
  autor = autor.chomp('*')
  listnew.puts nome << "\t" << autor
}
```

The problem I'm having is it only works for the last line in a file. For the other ones, the `\t` spacing is very small, and the last * doesn't get cut. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your split matches a *space* followed by a *.

You may want to split on '*' instead of ' *'.

I tried your code, it works for every line of my test file.

Comment: It only works here when I change the split, like you suggested. I don't get why, though. Thanks!

Comment: Odd.. I suspect a charset or similar issue. Newlines are CR, CR/LF, or LF? I'm on Linux.

Comment: I guess LF, since I'm on a Mac.